# How to make a series of time per class using a feature collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am working with severity of the fires, for this I vectored the severity sections and exported them to my asset, then I tried to use my feature collection to make a series of time per severity section (low, medium, high), however, I only throws a result
Could you help me, I do not know if the error is when I export or when I call the feature collection

```
// Run reduceToVectors per class by masking all other classes.
var classes = ee.List([0, 1, 2, 3])
  .map(function(n) {
    var classImage = severidad.eq(ee.Number(n));
    var vectors = classImage.updateMask(classImage)
      .reduceToVectors({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
        geometry: incendio, 
        scale: 30,
       // eightConnected: false,
        maxPixels: 1e8})
      .geometry();
    return ee.Feature(vectors, {"class": n,"size":vectors.area(1)});
  });
var result = ee.FeatureCollection(classes);
Map.addLayer(result);
Map.centerObject(result)
print(classes);    

// Export an ee.FeatureCollection as an Earth Engine asset.
Export.table.toAsset({
  collection:  result.filterMetadata('size', 'greater_than',0),
  description:'cochamo',
  assetId: 'severidad_Cochamo',
});
```

Link first part  here
https://code.earthengine.google.com/5ea068880b269f30b16afcb5e618ced7

Time series.
I try to make the time series with the vectors that I export in part I, but it does not work for me. I do not know how to select the three features that make up the feature collection, which is what I have to do with the time series.

```
var NDVITimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:NDVIbyyear ,
  regions:  severidad,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  band: 'NDVI',
  scale: 200,
  xProperty: 'year',
  seriesProperty: 'label'
});
NDVITimeSeries.setChartType('ScatterChart');
NDVITimeSeries.setOptions({
  title: 'NDVI',
  vAxis: {
    title: 'NDVI'
  },
  lineWidth: 1,
  pointSize: 4,
  series: {
            0: {color: 'FF0000'}, // severidad baja
            1: {color: '00FF00'}, // severidad media
            2: {color: '0000FF'}  // severidad alta

    }});

print(NDVITimeSeries);
```

link second part here
https://code.earthengine.google.com/3f54352b1bbe46a5982f1cf49e79c3f8

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d99aca0d9c420a77ab19bf9911e9443b)

This code should work. I combined the two scripts (the first with exporting worked fine?). For the graph, you had to set the seriesProperty to 'class' instead of 'label'